# Explanation for the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $F(x) = \int_a^x f(x)\ dx$. The proof starts like this:

$$\frac{F(x_0+h) - F(x_0)}{h} = \frac{1}{h}\cdot \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f(x)\ dx = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} \frac{f(t)-f(x_0)}{h}\ dt$$

Why is the second equality holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h} f(x)\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\Big( f(x)-f(x_0)+f(x_0)\Big)\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: I hate to say that but I still don't get it.

Comment: No problem. $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}(f(x)-f(x_0)+f(x_0))dx=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x_0)dx+\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{h}dx$$ and since $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x_0)dx=f(x_0)\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}dx=f(x_0)(x_0+h-x_0)=hf(x_0)$$ you get the result. Do you have it now ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!